# Elephant Toothpaste demo: How to concentrate hydrogen peroxide (freezer?)

Tags: experimental-chemistry, home-experiment

I would love to do an 'elephant toothpaste' demo in my Chemistry classes this week, but I do not have enough time to order 30% $\ce{H2O2}$ from a supply company.  I have been reading (and seeing on YouTube), however, that some people choose to create their own concentrated $\ce{H2O2}$ (concentration allegedly in the vicinity of 20-35%) by putting 3% $\ce{H2O2}$ in the freezer overnight, then separating the concentrated $\ce{H2O2}$ from the then-frozen water.

My ideal plan would be to use all of the $\ce{H2O2}$ that I produce during my classes throughout the day.  I've never worked with concentrated $\ce{H2O2}$ and so would like to ask.

1. Would anyone here actually recommend this method to me, given that I would be using this in class for the Elephant Toothpaste demo?  Are there any safety-related deal-breakers that I should be aware of?
2. What is the highest possible concentration of $\ce{H2O2}$ I could feasibly achieve by storing a bottle in a school's lunch-room freezer overnight?  I don't need anything above ~30% and would just love to know if this method has the potential to make >35% concentrations.
3. If I do happen to have extra $\ce{H2O2}$, what is the simplest way for me to dispose of it responsibly?  I know that $\ce{H2O2}$ will eventually decompose into $\ce{H2O}$ and $\ce{O2}$, and would rather not have to find a way to store home-made $\ce{H2O2}$ of an unknown concentration, but want to be safe and responsible with any disposal methods I use.

Comment: It is a very very bad practice to put chemicals in a fridge used for food storage. It is a safety consideration that you shouldn't violate. Especially if there are others that don't know about the "experiment."

Comment: @MaxW I appreciate your concern, but I am not sure what you are trying to warn me of.  Some of the substances found in home refrigerators are what we might think of as "chemicals" (not specifically intended for consumption), such as baking soda (an open box is often used to enhance "freshness"), vinegar (effectively diluted acetic acid), and even gel-based cold packs generally kept in freezers.  If we really want to go into detail, we could accurately say that everything in a refrigerator is a "chemical" product.  Hydrogen Peroxide decomposes into water and oxygen.  Is there a specific risk?

Comment: @MaxW I'm sorry, the rest of your comment was initially hidden, and I didn't get past the first sentence.  If I were to tell my colleagues not to touch the freezer bottle (I know they would not), what are the specific potential safety risks that I would be taking?  I definitely understand that if someone were to take the bottle out and start fiddling with it, there could be problems, but the same would go for the rest of my chemical supply.  If everyone were to heed my request, should I have any reason to think that the H2O2 would damage or contaminate anything in the fridge or freezer?

Comment: My point is simply that you shouldn't try to rationalize that putting chemicals in a school lunch fridge is safe. Anytime that you're sure that you've made something idiot proof, you've vastly underestimated the intelligence of idiots. // I'm a chemist, so I fully understand that a strawberry is a bag of chemical;s. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I do definitely see your point.  I probably won't end up doing this in the school fridge then.  In theory, though, are there any specific risks I should consider, beyond those associated with working with a relatively strong oxidizer and specific to the case of a plastic bottle in the freezer?  My students see so many DIY chemistry "experiments" on YouTube, and I really want to be able to give them good, chemistry-based explanations of how safe or not the author was (since my students are curious about that).  This understanding would generally add to my ability to answer their Q's.

Comment: I have seen a number of youtube videos that are extremely reckless. Often a basic safety requirement like safety glasses isn't met. What happens if you dump the acid on yourself? Where is the safety shower and eyewash?

Comment: I feel like you are assuming that I am a reckless chemist, and I do not appreciate that.  I am trying to be a voice of reason for my students who ARE often reckless/forgetful but who are also trying to be proud individuals, and I find that saying "don't do it, it's not safe" generally makes them feel belittled, and they don't listen.  They might do sthg just because I said not to.  If I can provide them with an explanation of chemistry involved, they listen.  I came to this forum with a legitimate request for help with my own chemical understanding.  Please let me know if you can provide that.

Comment: Here is a link using 12% H2O2 which can be bought at a beauty supply store. https://www.stevespanglerscience.com/lab/experiments/elephants-toothpaste/  // beauty supply link -- http://www.using-hydrogen-peroxide.com/hairdressing-peroxide.html

Comment: The first consideration of any chemical experiment is understanding what safety procedures are needed. Also how to safely dispose of chemical waste. // "Small" quantities of hydrogen peroxide solutions ( a quart, not a railroad tanker car...) can be disposed of with no special treatment. You can safely pour them down the drain of a sink while flushing with water.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate this.  My original, ideal situation was to purchase 30% from an educational chemical distributor, since that was called for in the curriculum I'm currently using.  I'll probably purchase the 12% you linked me to for this year, but in the future, if I were to use 30% in the demo and have left over solution, can I still drain and flush it?  If I buy a 500mL bottle, for example, but can only use 50 mL each in 6 class demos, can I store the remainder for a year (in an expandable accordion bottle), dilute it then drain it, just drain it, etc.?  Just want to be clear.

Comment: H2O2 degrades with time. If you use 50ml*6classes = 300 ml then you won't have enough for another year. Why keep it then?

Comment: That makes sense, I just don't know how quickly it would degrade, and so was thinking in extreme hypothetical terms so that I could push the limits of my understanding.  I suppose if I kept 200 mL and it kept well enough for a year, the following year I may only need to purchase a 100 mL container to come back to 300 mL total, but I won't bank on it.  If I buy a 500 mL bottle next year and need to dispose of 200 leftover mL safely, how can I do it?

Comment: I have to ask the question of why do the elephant's toothpaste experiment, what part of chemistry will it teach the students ?